# Capitalized letters in method name after wrongly assigning colUMN variable

Tags: vba, properties

I wrongly assigned `colUMN` variable, then changed to `colN` but VBA has started to act all `Column` method with `colUMN`.

When I use intellisense it is written as `Column`, but when I press enter  it goes back to `colUMN`.
It works as `range.Column` property fine.

I think I changed the property of VBA unwittingly. Will it be bad for my further code?

Comment: No. And to fix it, put `Dim Column`, then remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB Project Editor tries its best to keep capitalization consistent on each variable name that you type, but it does occasionally mess up. But its just that, capitalization, it doesn't actually mess up the code. Although it might be written colUMN, the `Range` object still only has a property called `Column` and when the code runs, it will properly give its `Column` value.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I also looked vba capitalization topic. But after that event, what I realized my editor toolbar sometimes ignores indent buttons. I mean After this capitalization event, sometimes indentation toolbar does not work. That's why I asked if it did modify something major in vba core modules